# React-native mystical text encoding

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Sometimes the `<Text>` renders with the wrong encoding... but after rerender everything works correctly. Any guesses why this can happen?

I have problems with text from server. Server always send utf-8 data.

[image: correct view]
[image: problem view]

Comment: You mean you have no problems with text from server.?

Comment: Yes. I found the problem... axios lib

Comment: Simple ```fetch()``` calls always return correct results.

Comment: Cool, congratulation.